# Why does Hilbert filter distorts the shape of the signal?

Tags: fourier-transform, finite-impulse-response, fourier-series, hilbert-transform

If all the harmonics composing a the signal are shifted by the same amount, this would be the same as sampling later or earlier in time. I think.

Take a simple pulse train as an example.
If Fourier is performed when the pulse is high for time t after 0, and flat for time t before the 0 it will have odd symmetry and only sin harmonics. If the same signal was sampled differently with half of the pulse left of y-axis and other half right of it, it would have even symmetry and contain only cos terms.

Each time actual signal is the same, just its Fourier representation is different.

[image]

Difference between these is only shifting all harmonics by 90 degrees. Why is Hilbert filter different in those regards?

I know square wave passed through Hilbert filter produces sideways curly braces like shape, so my fundamental understanding of something is wrong. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the width of the rectangular signal in your figure equals half the period, then the corresponding Fourier series can indeed be written as a weighted sum of sines (left-hand side signal) and a weighted sum of cosines (right-hand signal). Taking the signal on the right-hand side in your figure as an example, its Fourier series can be written in the form

$$x_1(t)=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\cos\left(\frac{2\pi n}{T}t\right)\tag{1}$$

And since the even Fourier coefficients are zero (apart from $a_0$), the series in $(1)$ can be rewritten as

$$x_1(t)=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{2n+1}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi (2n+1)}{T}t\right)\tag{2}$$

The Hilbert transform of $(2)$ is simply obtained by replacing the cosines with sines:

$$\mathcal{H}\{x_1(t)\}=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{2n+1}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi (2n+1)}{T}t\right)\tag{3}$$

However, this expression is different from the Fourier series of the signal on the left-hand side in your figure, which can be obtained by shifting $x_1(t)$ by $T/4$:

$$\begin{align}x_2(t)=x_1(t-T/4)&=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{2n+1}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi (2n+1)}{T}(t-T/4)\right)\\&=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{2n+1}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi (2n+1)}{T}t-n\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\&=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{2n+1}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi (2n+1)}{T}t-n\pi\right)\\&=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{2n+1}(-1)^n\sin\left(\frac{2\pi (2n+1)}{T}t\right)\tag{4}\end{align}$$

This expression has only sine terms, as expected, but it is clearly different from the Hilbert transform $(3)$, because shifting also changes the series coefficients.